# How to add custom styles and colors into PrimeVue components?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I need to set my custom styles and colors for PrimeVue components but keep it functionality. What is the best way to do it, best practice? In my mind I think I have to copy default theme.css file from node_modules of PrimeVue, create my new file _theme.css, paste from theme.css into my file, change neccessary styles over there and use it instead of theme.css. But it seems to have a lot of replacements in this file, is it okay?

I've replaced default file with the new one and changed styles over there, but I think it's not the best way to customize components

Comment: Did you check the docs? https://primevue.org/theming/